# Which Standard Exception Class to Use For Protocol Violations?

Tags: python, exception, protocols

According to a given protocol (which I cannot change, only implement), some function `initialize_foo()` is supposed to be called only once:

```
 def initialize_foo():
     """
     ...
     Note:
          You must call this function exactly once.
     """
```

I would like to recognize a protocol abuse where it is called twice, and raise an exception:

```
 _foo_initialized = False

 def initialize_foo():
     """
     ...
     Note:
          You must call this function exactly once.
     """
     if _foo_initialized:
         raise <what>?

     ...
     _foo_initialized = True
```

The problem is what class's object to raise. Looking at the [standard exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), I can't find anything to subclass except `Exception`, which seems too general.

What is the general practice in this case?

Comment: Do you have to crash if you initialize twice or are you about to catch it later on and keep on running?

Comment: Good point, @GLaDOS (love the name (and the game!), BTW) - on my level, all I know is that I need to raise to indicate that the call is illegal. Client decisions are beyond my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `RuntimeError`.

It is often used for that sort of stuff, even in the standard library. You can find an example very similar to your use case in the [`warnings` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/90d5473b8673/Lib/warnings.py#l361):

```
if self._entered:
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot enter %r twice" % self)
```

Another example is in [`threading`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/90d5473b8673/Lib/threading.py#l828):

```
if self._started.is_set():
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
```

You can also consider raising an ad-hoc exception (possibly a subclass of `RuntimeError`) if that error is supposed to be caught and if you feel that `RuntimeError` may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to subclass a **[warning](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#warnings)**, instead of having an exception, since I have a feeling that a lot of times you'd rather continue running after this happens.

Comment: That's interesting. I'm a bit apprehensive about raising a subclass of `Warning` (although it is certainly technically possible). Thanks.